# How to modify node.js lib files?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to modify the code in a lib file of node.js (see https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4056). However, it seems that when I put that code directly into the file in my lib folder, there's no effect even when I restart node. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you rebuilding node after editing the file?

Comment: do you mean remake? sorry, I'm not too sure how node works..

Comment: Yes using the instructions in the readme: https://github.com/joyent/node#to-build (I'm learning node as well)